# Need help proving some equivalance classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the equivalence relation mod m on the integers prove that if x=y(mod m) then [x]=[y].

The farthest I can get is:

```
Assume that x=y(mod m).
This means that x-y=mq for some integer q.
=> x = mq+y.
```

And then I stuck. Anybody able to help me?

Comment: It seems like $[x]=[y]$ in this case is defined to mean that $x=y \mod m$. Do you mean that you want to prove that $x=y \mod m$ is an equivalence relation?

Comment: No, the question already tells me that mod m is an equivalence relation.

Comment: OK, then what does $[x]$ mean?

Comment: It means the equivalence class of x. It's also sometimes written as x/R.

Comment: OK, so really what you want to know is that if $R$ is an equivalence relation and $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$, then $xRy$ implies $[x] = [y]$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $R$ is an equivalence relation on some set $X$ and $x R y$ for $x, y \in X$. Let $z \in [x]$. Then $z R x$. Then we have $z R x$ and $x R y$, so by transitivity, $z R y$. That is, $z \in [y]$. Hence $[x] \subset [y]$.

The reverse inclusion is similar.